# French vs Italian resistance

Tags: lateral-thinking

I have computed that the French resistance is roughly 17% larger than the Italian one. Do you know how I did it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Because ...

> ... the [coloured bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code) on a resistor with the colours of the French flag, blue – white – red, indicate an electric resistance of 6,900 ohms, whereas the colours of the Italian flag, green – white – red, indicate a value of only 5,900 ohms.
>
>  The value of 6,900 ohms is 16.95% higher than 5,900 ohms.

Comment: That's Great! :) +1

Comment: Of course Oehm gets that one.  :)

Comment: @Rubio: Hehe. `:)`

Comment: Hahaha, the same old question but with best answer by perfect person to answer it. @MOehm