# Making a physicist

Tags: riddle, physics

Materials:

> - CV
> - step-up transformer with coil ratio 1:5

Method:

> Apply the CV to the primary coil and spin it.

Result: A physicist is output. Who?

Hint 1:

> $\Omega$

Hint 2:

> $\Large\sim$

Comment: Should this have the [tag:knowledge] tag?

Comment: @maxathousand - I think the Physics tag covers the needed knowledge (school level). This physicist has been awarded the highest honours.

Comment: Spin it just means it needs to be changing, maybe a better wording would be update it. (This was understood by earlier answers.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The physicist is:

> [Paul **Dirac**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dirac).

Let's go though this step by step:

- > **CV** means **100 V** when we interpret C as Roman numeral.
- > **100 V** at the primary coil yield **500 V** at the secondary coil.
  > (Jafe had already done this calculation much earlier.)
- > This is alternating current, so the **500 V** are **500 VAC**.
  > (The tilde in the second hint is a symbol for AC.)
- > Now for the masterstroke: V can mean both volts and voltage and everyone is familiar with Ohm's law: *V* = *I*·*R*, right? We now have **500 IRAC**. (Groan at will. And don't do this in your physics assignments, kids!)
- > Finally, convert the number to Roman again. What's the word? **DIRAC**!

Now, isn't physics fun? `:)`

Comment: Groooooooan (also great answer!) :D (+1) from me!

Comment: @M Oehm please tell me your username is pronounced the same way as Ω (ohm) :)

Comment: @nikki: No,it isn't. The oe is equivalent to the umlaut ö, which is pronounced differently. The similarity of the names [was noted before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46395/french-vs-italian-resistance/46396#46396). (I'm probably better at obscure wordplay than at electronics, so that's where the similarities end.)

Comment: Aww that's too bad! :)

Comment: Well, the pronunciation is close enough, and since there is no representation of oe/ö in English, you can pronounce them the same if you like. (But I think I have heard most of the Oehm/Ohm puns already.)

Answer (score 22):

I'm going to go with

> [D. V. Nanopoulos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimitri_Nanopoulos)

because...

> A step-up transformer outputs a larger voltage than it receives. With coil ratio 1:5, this amounts to five times the input voltage (methinks?).
>
>  C is the Roman numeral for 100, so CV is a 100 volts. Output is then 500 volts, or DV.
>
>  D.V. Nanopoulos is a physicist whose initials are DV.

Comment: It was interesting reading about Professor Nanopoulos for the first time. This answer  stepped-up well.

Comment: This answer is distingushed, but some extra physics will lead to a famous physicist.

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> Nikola Tesla? That looks a lot like a recipe for a tesla coil

Answer (score 3):

Every neuron in my brain is telling me this is wrong, but as a desperation guess are you talking about

> Albert Einstein?

Reasoning:

> CV in Roman numerals is 105. If you divide this by 5 (even though you ought to multiply I think? I don’t know transformers very well) you get 21. 1921 is the year in which Einstein won the Nobel Prize (top honours for a Physicist) for the Photoelectric Effect.

Hints:

> The $\Omega$ might refer to $\Omega_{\Lambda}$, which is related to Einstein’s [cosmological constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant). The $\large\sim$ might refer to $E = \tilde{h}v$, found in the [Planck-Einstein relation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation).

Answer (score 2):

After the newly added hint I am going to guess the Physicist is...

> Edwin Hall

Reference

> You mention the symbol Ω which is the symbol for an ohm which was first conceptualized by the german physicist Georg Ohm.  But I thought this was too easy and I learned that, "today the definition of the ohm is expressed from the Quantum Hall effect."  This pointed me to the man who first discovered this effect Edwin Hall.

Just a guess though as my physics knowledge doesn't extend past high school

Comment: +1 for the education. It may shock some that I once taught high school Physics (not my main subject). I didn't know this though vaguely remember hearing of the Hall effect.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> James Prescott Joule

Because

> CV is the 3rd letter and the 22 letter
>  322 on the primary coil will result in 1610 on the secondary coil
>  16 and 10 are P and J
>  the PJ or Pico Joule is named after James Joule

Hint 1

> Joule's first law, is about Ohmic heating

Hint 2

> don't know

Comment: Great answer!! Isn’t 16 P rather than K, though?

Comment: @El-Guest oops, i stopped 5 too early.  well maybe that still works

Comment: that’s a solid replacement answer, +1 from me!!

Answer (score 1):

El Guest has already come up with Albert Einstein.  I would like to provide a better reasoning. As C = 3, CV = 3 Volts and the step-up transformer outputs 15 Volts. 1 = A and 5 = E. There you have Albert Einstein.
The explanation of the hints are as same as that of El Guest.